# Using return is valid on global scope?

Tags: javascript

Using return is valid if code execution is not inside of a function or in the other i am totally on global scope.

```
var x = y + 1
if(x == 10)
  return;//visual studio gives warnings and says that "return keyword is not inside a function"
```

Comment: How do you think it's valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not. This makes a syntax error if it isn't inside a function.

From [the ECMAScript spec](http://es5.github.io/#x12.9) :

> An ECMAScript program is considered syntactically incorrect if it contains a return statement that is not within a FunctionBody.

Note that some browsers don't follow the spec rigorously :

- Firefox is correct in refusing to execute the code
- Chrome, incorrectly, accepts to run the code until it has to execute that faulty statement

Comment: It isn't. Write a HTML file with a JS block containing your code and you'll get a syntax error if `x==10` (browsers *should* make a syntax error in all cases but some don't).

Comment: @Freshblood jsfiddle code is executed inside a function.